# How to enable ldap authentication in php

Tags: php, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, ldap, windows-authentication

I have one server (Windows Server 2012 R2) and I need to configure
a LDAP users authentication in PHP. Server is domain controller, PHP (5.6) is installed and PHP already has LDAP extension. Bind with credentials in ldp.exe works.

**WHAT I KNOW:**

- LDAP connection works
- I can log on anonymously
- I cannot log in with user credentials (even with admin credentials)

I've tried edit policy "Default Domain Controller"

- Domain Controller: LDAP server signing requirements

  > NONE
- Network Security: LDAP client signing requirements

  > NEGOTIATE SIGNING

**PHP CODE:**

```
// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'bigboss';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'AdmiN123';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap://172.16.31.70")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {
    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I need to edit

```
$ldaprdn  = 'bigboss'
```

to

```
$ldaprdn  = '[domain name]\bigboss'
```

Thanks